# Boot messages available over serial, however no login prompt :/

Tags: boot, debian, serial

I've connected to the Raspberry Pi using a serial programmer for my [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino). I've connected using screen and when I boot my Raspberry Pi it spits out all the normal kernel boot messages.

However, at the end of the output, there is no login prompt, so I am unable to use my Raspberry Pi through the serial port.

I've tried [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software), [Pidora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Operating_systems), and [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) with no luck on either. There must be something simple I am missing, but what is it!

Comment: this serial console how to should get you going https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto looks like you jsut setup inittab to run getty with your serial parameters

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in `/etc/inittab`, and you will find lines like:

```
# Example how to put a getty on a serial line (for a terminal)
#
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100
#T1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS1 9600 vt100
```

Which set up how getty listen at the given device.

In this case, the following needs to be added:

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

As the Raspberry Pi uses ttyAMA0 as its serial port. Reboot your Raspberry Pi and you should now be able to connect with, for example, screen and login.