# I couldn't see cmdline.txt in my mac

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I am following this [article](https://kushrami.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/how-to-start-raspberry-pi-without-screen/) to install raspberrypi without monitor. I loaded the card but couldn't see cmdline.txt.

What am missing here ?

[image]

Comment: In case the duplicate is not clear, on NOOBS `recovery.cmdline` is effectively the same thing.

Comment: Check Part 4 in the accepted answer. He kept mentioning cmdline.txt, while he is editing the file that you have mentioned earlier recovery.cmdlin http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display

Comment: That's because in that answer NOOBS is being used to install raspbian, *after* which there should be a `cmdline.txt`.

Comment: Your answer was obsolete and misleading. On NOOBS recovery.cmdline is "NOT" effectively the same thing, you should install Raspbian, and then edit cmdline.txt. Thanks for ur time anyway.