# Using my Raspberry Pi without HDMI TV

Tags: hdmi

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi. Since I don't have an HDMI TV, I just have a laptop with anolog OUTPUT.

This is what I bought: [Raspberry Pi 2 - MODB - 1GB - Quad core](http://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-MODB-Quad-core/dp/B00T7EE3D0?tag=googinhydr18418-21&kpid=B00T7EE3D0&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=bb5f0025-da76-426a-a185-9886f76964a7)

Comment: What sort of analog input? VGA? if so, look for an (active) HDMI -> VGA converter (and look for a low-powered one such that the Pi can power it up via HDMI) - or, you can just use an Ethernet cable and log in remotely to get things going if you don't care much for the GUI

Comment: If there's an analog input on your laptop it's for a microphone.

Comment: Appologies ! I ment analog VGA output.

Comment: Alternative: *[Installing Raspbian from NOOBS without display](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with laptops having analog video input (video capture could work, but I have never seen one built in). So I agree that in the long run you want to setup ssh.

The problem is that most instructions for setting up ssh for Raspberry Pi assume that you have access to an HDMI monitor or TV. So one option is to borrow such a monitor for a couple of hours and setup ssh. (DVI-D monitors will work with the right cable.)

The next option is to set up a serial connection using the header and a RS-232 driver such as the MAX232 family of chips or a USB serial adapter chip and connect that way, but you would have to wire it by hand. The third way to do this is to setup ssh before installing the SD card. This would require running a Raspberry Pi emulator on your laptop or really knowing [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) well enough to install ssh just by editing the file system. If my answer confuses you, just borrow a monitor.

Comment: I think I will borrow a monitor.Lets see how things turn out.I will get back to you with a update.

Answer (score 1):

Piyush, not sure what you mean with analog Input.
The solution is to set-up a network connection between the Pi and your laptop and use SSH.

Here is a very good instruction which helped me to achieve that kind of connection.

https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/

Comment: My bad! I was supposed to write analog output !

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.