# Is there a way to do a slient install on a raspberry pi, but to also include setup information while installing?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, noobs

First of all, I know how to setup a slient install given a list of instructions provided in another question: ([Installing Raspbian from NOOBS without display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display))

However, I need this thing to setup its wifi connection, install a package during the installation, and change its keyboard setting to US. Is there a way to tell the NOOBs installer to do this during installation?

Comment: Is making a cloned image out of the question?  Because you could just do a win32diskimager/dd copy of the memory and just clone the memory.

Comment: Out of the question, because I have multiple ones I need to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst

This is a silent netinstall that will do everything automatically and only requires a network connection.

You can modify setup files before running it on the Raspberry Pi and add packages you want to be additionally installed and so on. Read through the git page and Wiki.

I use for my Raspberry Pi. To be honest it's 100x better than the bloated Raspbian image from raspberrypi.org.

Comment: this sounds like something I might be able to use, but there is a custom program I need in there isn't available in the repository. How would I do that with this?

Comment: You need to modify https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/master/update.sh and add the reposity for the application you need. Then write a routine to install it via that update.sh when it's running and updating the packages.