# Pulled out sd card while doing silent install

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, software-installation

So, I was doing an installation of Raspbian without a monitor or keyboard, as outlined [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19928/34074) and I was at the stage where you insert the sd card with some changed configuration files and wait for it to install. However, during this process I have accidentally pressed on the card and it removed from its slot. I put it back in, but now the only light flashing is red, I guess it is the power light. What should I do now? Will I need to somehow reboot the installation?

Update: following recommendations, I have tried powering it off, reinserting the sd card and powering it on again. Still nothing. When I plugged the sd card into my main computer it had 2 partitions, one called BOOT, I guess the installation started before I interrupted it. I have formatted the sd card and put NOOBS on it. After inserting the card back into rpi the green light flashes for a bit and then nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried a power cycle?  I.e. switch off, insert the SD card, power on.  See if the green LED flashes.

Comment: @joan did it now, will see how it goes...

Comment: Don't insert or remove the SD card with the power on.  There's nothing that can be accomplished that way.  As joan says, to boot properly, you need to apply power with a card already inserted.  If you insert it after that, nothing will happen.

Comment: the green light flashed for a bit, now it's back to red only. I am doing ping raspberrypi.local and it says "Unknown host".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have sorted it out. I just reformatted the sd card and started a new installation. Worked perfectly.