# Installing new OS over ssh

Tags: ssh, sd-card, retropie

I currently have OpenELEC insalled on my PI and I want to install retropie instead. I do not have a micro sd adapter or reader on my computer. Is it possible for me to install the new operating system over ssh?

Comment: I don't know how you installed OpenELEC in the first place, but if you are using NOOBS you might want to take a look at [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display) question.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Not really. If you have extra space on the card and:

- This space is big enough for retropie.
- You have enough space left in your openELEC root filesystem to download the retropie to.

Then you might be able to:

1. Create an extra partition.
2. [Mount the partitions in the image.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538)
3. Copy the contents of the retropie root fs onto the new partition in the card.
4. Copy the retropie kernel into the boot partition and modify `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt` appropriately.

And you should be able to get retropie to boot, but this would not *replace* openELEC since it would still be there.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option if you have a linux machine available: booting over nfs. Once you booted over nfs, you are able to modify the root partition/filesystem of your openELEC partition since it is not used so far. You can particularly delete it and replace it with retropie, as goldilocks described in his answer.