# My password doesn't work over ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh, noobs, headless

I am trying a headless install and using NOOBS v1.4.2 .

I followed the instructions on this thread: [Installing Raspbian from Noobs without display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display) and changed the password on \os\Raspbian\os.json and kept the same username.

I found the IP of the PI over my network and tried to connect it by

```
ssh pi@192.168.x.x
pi@192.168.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.x.x's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I also tried the default password 'raspberry' .. still no luck

Is there something I am missing here? SSH seems to be working and activated on install. I made all the changes suggested on that thread. Still can't get anything though.

Comment: Did you try the default password ("raspberry")?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried that already (updated question to point that out)

Comment: Try it with `ssh -v ...` and edit in the output.

Comment: I read the link. It is very clever, but convoluted! Why would you want to go to this much trouble when you can just install Raspbian. NOOBS is really designed for people who don't have SD facilities to copy an image.

Comment: I downloaded NOOBS when I had a keyboard and display around me. By the time I got to configure the Pi, I didn't have those accessories and was in a low-bandwidth place, so was not interested in spending a night downloading Raspbian!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response you are getting is telling you the answer. You are not providing the correct password. This means one of the following has occurred:

1. When you attempted to change the password, you did not do this correctly
2. When you enter the password, you are not entering it correctly

Try starting over. I would suggest that you *not* change the pi's password until a later stage, after you have things set up for your intended use.

Comment: That's right. I changed it as advised (in that tutorial)  in the os.json file but that didn't work. The default was still on and I went into config to change it later.

Comment: Oh good. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

This could be related to the default UK keyboard used on the RPi. I used a special character in my password and this converted to " on the default UK keyboard and Locale. Make sure you set the Locale and Keyboard that match what you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the default password, `raspberry`, is actually the default password for your pi operating system.

I just realized, for example, that the pi-top operating system has a default password of `pi-top`, which is a super annoying thing for them to do, but it is what it is.

Comment: This is an entirely bad suggestion. The password for the `pi` userid should be ANY string other than `raspberry` or `pi-top` as those are well known. RaspiOS checks for that on first boot and requests that you change the password to any string known by you and you alone.

Comment: @Dougie this thread is for people logging into their Pi for the first time, so they are going to be using the default password. I'm not suggesting anything about how they setup users or deal with security after that.

Answer (score 0):

Extreme edge case: if you happen to be using a clipboard manager, try typing the password in like someone with real fingers… Habitually pasting from Launchbar failed across two re-installs before I thought to actually type the password `<face palm>`