# Noobs Lite - automatically install Raspbian

Tags: noobs, setup

I'd like to build a Raspbian setup process, where the user needs to do as less as possible. That's why I'd like to use Noobs Lite but to start the setup it's still necessary to have a display and mouse, to choose Raspbian and hit install. I just know its working using the normal Noobs package (size > 1GB) to do a [silent install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display).

Is it possible to preconfigure the Noobs Lite package, so Raspbian will automatically be downloaded and installed?

Comment: NOOBS Lite is [differentiated from NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) by being "the same operating system installer *without Raspbian pre-loaded*".  So now instead of just using NOOBS, *"which contains Raspbian"*, you want to use the version **without Raspbian**, but then ask "Is it possible to preconfigure the Noobs Lite package, so Raspbian will automatically be downloaded and installed"???  By analogy: "I ordered a widget from Acme but I do not want to get it shipped by them because they use UPS.  How can I get UPS to ship the widget to me from Acme instead?"

Comment: Exactly, where is the problem? I want to keep the users work as small as possible including downloading. I don't know why it strikes your mind to do that, because I do want to use Raspbian but I do not want to have it pre-loaded. The reason is that the download takes too long synchronous time of the user, Noobs Lite would be asynchronous. I just want to know whether there is a way to customise Noobs Lite, to do that.

Comment: Okay, so your idea is rather than wasting the user's time with a download which includes everything required, you will have them waste their time with a download which doesn't, then inform them afterward, "Oh sorry that was only the beginning...now wait while we download the rest...".  I would call that a problem but this is only a (reasonable) opinion.  The more serious problem is that if you ask how to do something no reasonable person needs to do, then you are unlikely to end up with much of an answer.

Comment: For my use, it's the best solution that the user has a short download-time and a quick drag&drop. Thanks for sharing your concerns but I just want to have an answer to my question, whether I can preconfigure Noobs Lite.

Answer (score 2):

No, because you have to download raspbian from the web with NOOBS Lite. Download the full NOOBS, which contains the raspbian and make your life easier.