# Noobs: Offline intallation without monitor and disabling network mirrors

Tags: raspbian, archlinux, noobs

I'm planning to install either Arch or Raspbian on my rp using Noobs(with offline installation option).
I have no HDMI monitor, so I will do it using ssh in "silent install mode" as described in this thread:
[Installing Raspbian from NOOBS without display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display?newreg=35e93a2bc522422fb57e265c8fa556d5)

The question:
How to modify Noobs to make sure that my distro will be installed offline and the network mirrors will be disabled?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are in for several problems.

1. NOOBS does not have `Arch`. [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) does have an `Arch` installer.
2. NOOBS is designed to be a "simple" installer, and requires a keyboard and screen. (It is possible to bypass this, but the steps involved are highly complex.) The link you listed is very old, for Wheezy.
3. `ssh` is disabled by default. It is possible to make it work in Raspbian by including a file `ssh` on the boot partition, but AFAIK this can't be done with NOOBS.

Comment: I've installed raspbian already... just stuck on enabling ssh. I've done this:  sudo su
cd /media/ubuntu/root
for i in 2 3 4 5; do sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh etc/rc$i.d/S02ssh; done
from kali, but it did not work..((

Comment: @Drew **DO NOT** paste detail into Comments, edit your question.